# Emacs lisp, How to make a newline in IELM?

Tags: emacs, newline

Even the basic things seem to be hidden behind weird shortcut-combinations.
How can I (hopefully without too many c-m-x-c combinations) create a simple new line?

return evaluates the current line

Answer (score 0):

With `C-j`. That said, if you have `paredit` enabled, it should do all the newlines you need automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `M-j`.

I'm currently trying out **SpaceMacs**, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Even the basic things seem to be hidden behind weird shortcut-combinations.

If you *don't* want <kbd>RET</kbd> to have contextual behaviour, you can <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `ielm-dynamic-return`.

> How can I ... create a simple new line?

Only a newline?  <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> is the normal way to enter a newline in places where <kbd>RET</kbd> does something else.  (More generally you can use <kbd>C-q</kbd> to insert any character that isn't self-inserting for the current buffer.)

If you want newline + indentation (which is what <kbd>RET</kbd> does when contextually appropriate), then <kbd>M-j</kbd> will do that (noting that if you are in a comment at the time then the new line will also default to a comment).